# create schema with dashdb on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

I have the 'small package' of the dashdb service in bluemix. I can't create a new schema. It fails with no authority.  I've read on another post that it's a limitation of the 'small package'. My question is: Is this limitation removed on other packages? ie. I don't want to upgrade to the $ package only to find the same restriction. 
Thank you, Dan

Comment: `CREATE SCHEMA <my schema name>`. Free/entry plan doesn't allow additional schemas. Full schema doc: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000925.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [service overview for dashDB](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/dashdb) there is either the entry plan (the "small package") which only has single schema support (one dedicated schema on a shared server) or there are different enterprise-level packages. They give you the full control in terms of schema creation.

The enterprise plans of dashDB are fully managed services (DBaaS). In the short service description is a email address you might want to contact if you need specifics.